# Mosquitto certificate verify failed with protocol error

Tags: ssl, mosquitto

I'm having trouble setting up mosquitto to encrypt over SSL/TLS. I have followed the instructions of mosquitto to generate the certificate and key. The code used is as follows:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -extensions v3_ca -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt.crt
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -out server.csr -key server.key -new
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out 
 server.crt.crt -days 3650
```

Then I configured in `mosquitto.conf` as follows:

```
listener 8883
allow_anonymous true
cafile d:\etc\mosquitto\ca_certificates\ca.crt.crt
certfile d:\etc\mosquitto\certs\server.crt.crt
keyfile d:\etc\mosquitto\certs\server.key
```

Then I used the code

```
mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf
```

The results of running mosquitto are as follows:

```
D:\etc\mosquitto>mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf
1663109874: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1663109874: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1663109874: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1663109874: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1663109874: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

But I have a problem when I want to try to make the subscribe and publish commands.I ran the following code:

```
mosquitto_sub -d -v -h 91.121.93.94 -p 8883 -t test --cafile d:\etc\mosquitto\ca_certificates\ca.crt.crt
```

`91.121.93.94` is the Common Name I set to generate the server key.Then I got the error as below:

```
Client null sending CONNECT
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed 
Error: protocol error
```

I don't know where I am going wrong or if I have not configured something in `mosquitto.conf`.

Comment: errr, `91.121.93.94` is the IPv4 address of the `test.mosquitto.org` machine, it will not verify with your CA cert. If you have replaced your real IP address with this, then please use an rfc1918 address or an obviously fake address, not somebody else's real broker IP.

Comment: thank you very much! I followed your method to rebuild the certificate and key, and it works fine now.  :)